# A curve val_loss and loss in keras after training a model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, cnn, accuracy

Can anyone help me, is my model overfitting or underfitting?
I want to make sure the model is well done before starting to deploy

Also, I use categorical cross-entropy loss

[image]

I have asked before, but I can't reply to anyone, so I put my question again with a new account

Answer (score 0):

01, welcome to the community!
In response to your question, from the graph above, there is currently no clear evidence of neither under- or over-fitting. The reasoning for it is the following:

- For overfitting, we would see the training loss continually dropping over epochs, whilst the validation loss plateaus over epochs. This would then show that the model is fitting to the noise and variance (and therefore overfitting).
- For underfitting, we would typically see both training and validation loss being consistently high (despite decreases over epochs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! doesn't it qualify as a good fitting?

Comment: Good question, good fitting is hard to define. But, looking at the minimum point of both training and validation error, I would say it is good. But, the hold-out test set (which is neither in the training or validation set) will be the ultimate test of how well the model performs on unseen examples.
The nice thing is about Data Science is then you can formulate hypotheses of how to further improve the fit (whilst meaning the ability for the model to perform well on unseen examples).